# Should a question be allowed to contain contact details?

Tags: discussion, questions

A question has been posted ([Mesh distortion on my models clothes when creating a pose](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87485/mesh-distortion-on-my-models-clothes-when-creating-a-pose)) that suggests that answers and information exchange could be done via instant messaging outside stack exchange, because of an exceptional urgency. The users also provides contact details (discord username) in order to be reached.

- A troubleshooting confrontation, if made public and permanent through comments and edits, is beneficial to other users (including who asked the question). Because of this, should the information about instant messaging and contact details be removed?

  Should the user be suggested to edit the question themselves to remove this information?

  Would the contact information (or a request for instant messaging, contact details being moved to the profile page) be acceptable in the comment section?

The post is on a First Post review queue and somewhat puzzles me.

Comment: meta-meta-question: can meta questions contain links to currently active main-site questions?

Comment: to answer your meta meta question, **yes** definitely. Any time you can link to real examples of the issue it is helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You start out with the correct assumption which is: contact info should not be in posts.

As such whenever you see this type of thing (usually an email address where you can contact them for more details) **edit it out.**
Nothing good comes from it. If you privately give the OP some answer off site, then nobody else can benefit from that answer. Likewise if the OP sends you more detailed information (that should be edited into the question) then nobody else has that to write an answer off of.

Users can have almost anything they want on their profile page, so sure their contact info can be there. However if you then find a question with something like this:

> If you need more screen shots you can find my contact info on my profile page.

Then just edit it out.

SE does not like extra "[noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/278094)" in posts things like "thanks" "hi" etc are encouraged to be edited out, how much more so someone's contact info.

You will find that every time this has been brought up on the main meta the same answer comes forward, **contact info should not be in posts.**

[Should I flag a question in which the OP includes their phone number?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212636/278094)
[Should (real) e-mail-addresses be forbidden in questions/answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148399/278094)
[Allow users to put their e-mail in posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37956/278094)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that pointing people to offsite contact (as in your "screen shot" example) is that then other answerers don't have the advantage of working from the same information when forming their answers, peer review stops happening, and the aid rendered doesn't go on to help other users. If a question needs more information it should be edited into the question.